# Are there other Android emulators besides the one with the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on an Android app for a client of mine, who is unfortunately not very tech savvy. The thought of installing the Android SDK to get to the emulator scares the hell out of them. Is there any third party Android emulators out there that provide the same functionality as the one provided with the SDK, but minus all of the development periphery?

They are in the middle of buying a bunch of Android phones now (physical), where they'll be able to eventually test on a hard device, but in the meantime, I figured this was the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed a minimum SDK (minus all the docs and platforms I didn't want) plus a Java runtime on a USB memory stick. Create an AVD on the stick, and put your app on it. Add a few batch files to start up the emulator etc, and give it to your client - all they need is any Windows box. It should fit on a 2GB stick easily enough and these are dirt cheap now.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Its a bit more obtuse than I would have expected, but that doesn't surprise me at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Android x86 in VirtualBox or VMWare.